What does DISM /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:VBSCRIPT~~~~ do to install VBScript?
I ask this because if all it does is add/restore vbscript.dll and do a regsvr32 vbscript.dll, then for new PCs where vbscript has to be available, it can be rolled into existing configuration scripts we already use. Copy the dll then trigger register.
Please no debating vbscript OMG no. These are new h/w deploys for LOB non-internet joined devices running a ton of legacy stuff. And no WIM applies here.

What version of Windows 11 are you running? VBScript should not have been removed unless you are running 24H2 or newer. Microsoft only recently released plans to remove VBScript

Check C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log for a pretty verbose explanation of what exactly it does. My guess is it at least installs the cscript.exe/wscript.exe launchers, associates the file extensions like .vbe and .vbs, and updates the dism database with the feature's installation status

@Ramhound
Haven't been bitten yet, so this is a) anticipating inevitable and b) looking for DIY solution for our own machines that can be added to the process we use for customization and tweaks - master .reg files that get merged, folder creation and file and link copies, e.g. Notepad++, etc.

@Cpt.Whale
We haven't been bitten yet, don't think anyone has AFIK. I don't know how they will remove it so can't simulate that on a VM image. Win 11 VMs also still has VBS so ditto there.

You don't have to do anything until 2027. Then you'll need to enable the VBScript FOD via your configuration script. See this article

@SKidd - So you want to know what a command does that isn’t necessary or can’t even be ran today since vBScript cannot be added or removed? How do we answer this question?

I’m voting to close this question because this command cannot be test. VBScript cannot be removed or added to Windows today.

@Ramhound  - Wrong.  It can be deleted today, DISM /Online /Remove-Capability /CapabilityName:VBSCRIPT~~~~

@LesFerch - Wrong, this is rolling soon on WIndows 11 24H2, which is, where we are, 2024 2nd half of year.  So yeah it's pressing.

It will remain enabled by default until 2027. 24H2 hasn’t been released outside of Insider Preview builds.

Yes; It appears that enabling the feature likely just registers the dynamic libraries, as explained that in phase 3 which will be sometime after 2027, the dynamic link library files will be removed.  “This means all the dynamic link libraries (.dll files) of VBScript will be removed.”, however, there is a possibility that once it’s disabled by default that these dynamic link library files would not exist outside of WinSxS by default, until enabled which would then “install” the files and register them like how nearly every optional feature works.

I suggest you actually take a look at 24H2. You will see that VBScript is still installed and enabled. The only new thing is that 24H2 includes an option to uninstall VBScript.

The command:
DISM /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:VBSCRIPT~~~~
is the reverse of
DISM /Online /Remove-Capability /CapabilityName:VBSCRIPT~~~~
which is the same as going to the Optional Features list in Windows 24H2 (or higher) and selecting Remove for the VBSCRIPT FOD (Feature On Demand).
The DISM command does far more than just add vbscript.dll and do a regsvr32 vbscript.dll. For example, it also adds back the 32 bit version in SysWOW64, adds the VBScript MUI files for all installed languages, adds the FOD package files for VBSCript, and adds a myriad of registry entries to associate VBS and VBE extensions, register COM objects, and so on.
Please note that VBScript is installed and fully functional in Windows 24H2. The only change, in regards to VBScript, is that 24H2 includes an option to remove VBScript.
According to Microsoft's announcement (see link below), VBScript will remain installed by default until sometime in 2027. At that point, VBScript will be uninstalled by default and then the above DISM command would be the recommended way to reinstall VBScript.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/vbscript-deprecation-timelines-and-next-steps/ba-p/4148301
